# Finding a closed form solution for an infinite sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, trigonometric-series, trigonometric-integrals, exponential-sum

I've come across a infinite series for which I've had difficulty finding a closed form solution:

$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \sin^2(\pi/i).$$

I believe that the series does converge and I've tried looking at transformations to different trig functions and exponentials, however the answer remains elusive. Putting this into WolframAlpha yields a numerical result however I'm much more interested in finding a closed form solution if one exists.

Would be swell if anyone could offer some guidance, thanks.

Comment: @mathworker21 thanks for the quick response, I've explored going down that route however I don't know how to resolve this sum with multiple terms (having the extra 1/2 in this case)

Comment: Don't know if finding closed form solution is possible. In your question you seem to be in doubt if the series converges. This is readily seen to hold by applying the comparison test, since the $n$-th term is asymptotically $\frac{\pi^2}{n^2}$.

Comment: [A269611](http://oeis.org/A269611) gives some equivalent series for this, but no closed form.

Comment: @Daniel Maybe I wasn't clear, I believe that it does converge which is why I hope there's a closed form solution

Comment: @automaticallyGenerated that's an interesting resource, I'll explore around a bit but yeah the equivalent functions all also involve another series of some type

Comment: @ThuyGuevarra I think the point was that you shouldn't just believe it converges. It obviously does converge, since $\sin(x)\sim x$ for small $x$

Comment: @mathworker21 Is my statement that I believe it converges incorrect whether or not I thought that fact was obvious?

Comment: @ThuyGuevarra Of course it's not incorrect.... I was just trying to explain what Daniel was saying.

Comment: @mathworker21 Ah gotcha, yeah I see what you mean. Just didn't want to use too strong language.

Answer (score 4):

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin^2(\frac{\pi}{n}) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1-\cos(\frac{2\pi}{n})}{2} = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left[\frac{4\pi^2}{2n^2}-\frac{2^4\pi^4}{4!n^4}+\frac{2^6\pi^6}{6!n^6}+\dots\right] = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\frac{2^{2n}\pi^{2n}}{(2n)!}\zeta(2n) = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\frac{2^{2n}\pi^{2n}}{(2n)!}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{B_{2n}(2\pi)^{2n}}{2(2n)!} = \frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{B_{2n}(2\pi)^{4n}}{(2n)!(2n)!}$

Comment: The second result still seems to not be closed, the first is interesting through how did you find that? The answer differs from what WolframAlpha yields

Comment: I don't know what you just said.

Comment: The second result is still an infinite sum, the first reduces to a constant but differs from the constant I get when I plug the equation into WolframAlpha.

Comment: I don't know what you just said.

Comment: @mathworker21  I think the user wants to know how you got each different series in your answer since you have no explanation.

Comment: how on earth did you get that the user wanted to know how i got **each different series** from their comments???????

Answer (score 1):

Using standard techniques to calculate infinite series via residue calculus one obtains that, if 
$$
\pi \cot (\pi z)=\frac{a_{-1}}{z}+a_1z+a_3z^3+\cdots+a_{2k-1}z^{2k-1}+\cdots
$$
then
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{2k}}=-2a_{2k-1}.
$$
Hence
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin^2\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(1-\cos\Big(\frac{2\pi}{n}\Big)\right)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\sum_{j=1}^\infty (-1)^{j-1} \frac{(2\pi)^{2j}}{(2j)!n^{2j}}\right)\\=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{j-1}(2\pi)^{2j}}{(2j)!}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{2j}}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{2(-1)^{j}(2\pi)^{2j}a_{2j-1}}{(2j)!}
$$

Comment: It's an interesting result, however there's still an infinite sum to be dealt with in the end